# Convert multiple images as pdf with multiple page

Tags: ios, pdf-generation

In my application there is a WebView with HTML contents. Contents is of 3 page in WebView .
Now i want to convert WebView content in PDF. I have created 3 image from the WebView content. Now i want to create pdf using these 3 image. Each image should one page of PDF. But it resulting as single page image. So when i am taking print then content is cut off.
I am using this,

```
CGSize pageSize = CGSizeMake(612, 2324);
NSString *fileName = @"Demo.pdf";
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFileName, CGRectZero, nil);

// Mark the beginning of a new page.
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);

double currentHeight = 0.0;

for (int index = 1; index <= imageName ; index++)
{
    NSString *pngPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", index]];
    UIImage *pngImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pngPath];

    [pngImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, currentHeight, pageSize.width, pngImage.size.height)];        
    currentHeight += pngImage.size.height;
}

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

What i am doing wrong with this code.

THanks

Comment: Are you trying to have all the content on 1 page?

Comment: About the only thing I can see "wrong" with the code is that the initial height of the page (2324) ***might*** be disconnected from the sum of the heights of the images. You iterate `currentHeight` using `pngImage.size.height`, which may not total up to 2324. Other than that, using my own PNG file, your code works. In my case, though, the third page (since its height is 960 pixels) is partially cut off.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*For call method*/

 [self createPdfWithName:@"sam" array:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"01.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"02.png"], nil]];

/*Create New Pdf*/

- (NSString *)createPdfWithName: (NSString *)name array:(NSArray*)images
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docspath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pdfFileName = [docspath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",name]];
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFileName, CGRectZero, nil);
    for (int index = 0; index <[images count] ; index++)
    {
        UIImage *pngImage=[images objectAtIndex:index];;
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, (pngImage.size.width), (pngImage.size.height)), nil);
        [pngImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, (pngImage.size.width), (pngImage.size.height))];
    }
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
    return pdfFileName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func createPDFS(arrImages: [UIImage]) -> NSData? {

        var pageHeight = 0.0
        var pageWidth = 0.0

        for img in arrImages
        {
            pageHeight =  pageHeight+Double(img.size.height)

            if Double(img.size.width) > pageWidth
            {
                pageWidth = Double(img.size.width)
            }
        }

        let pdfData = NSMutableData()
        let pdfConsumer = CGDataConsumer(data: pdfData as CFMutableData)!

       var mediaBox = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight)

       let pdfContext = CGContext(consumer: pdfConsumer, mediaBox: &mediaBox, nil)!

        for img in arrImages
        {
            var mediaBox2 = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: img.size.width, height: img.size.height)

                   pdfContext.beginPage(mediaBox: &mediaBox2)
            pdfContext.draw(img.cgImage!, in: CGRect.init(x: 0.0, y: 0, width: pageWidth, height: Double(img.size.height)))

              pdfContext.endPage()
        }

        return pdfData
    }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for your answer. Rather than just posting a block of code, can you give a short explanation to what the issue is you solved and how you solved it? This will help people who find this question in the future to better understand the issue and how to deal with it.

Answer (score -1):

```
CGSize pageSize = CGSizeMake(612, 2324);
NSString *fileName = @"Demo.pdf";
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFileName, CGRectZero, nil);       

double currentHeight = 0.0;

for (int index = 1; index <= imageName ; index++)
{
    NSString *pngPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", index]];
    UIImage *pngImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pngPath];

// TODO: See Here
// Mark the beginning of a new page.
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pngImage.size.height), nil);

    [pngImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, currentHeight, pageSize.width, pngImage.size.height)];        
    //currentHeight += pngImage.size.height;
}

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```